# Marginal and Average costs for constant returns to scale production function being constant

Tags: microeconomics, production-function

Suppose that we are dealing with a production function $q = f(k,l)$, of inputs capital and labor. If this function exhibits constant returns to scale then I know that both the marginal cost and average cost functions $C(q)$ are equal and constant for each of the inputs and the total. i.e:
$$\frac{\partial C(q)}{\partial q} = \frac{C(q)}{q}$$This means that the contingent demand for labor and capital must be  linear in $q$. Why is this is case mathematically and what is the economic interpretation?

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by "*what is the economic interpretation*"? Do you understand what "linear in $q$" means?

Comment: I get the economic interpretation that the marginal and average costs increase at a constant rate with respect to q, which makes sense for constant returns to scale. So I guess I just wanted to have a mathematical proof.

Answer (score 0):

Constant returns to scale (CRS) means that for any positive real number $a$
$$
f(a \cdot k,a \cdot l) = a \cdot f(k,l).
$$
Let us assume that industry wants to produce one unit of output. Then they face the unit cost minimization problem
$$
\min_{k,l} \ r \cdot k + w \cdot l 
$$
s.t.
$$
1 = f(k,l).
$$
Suppose this problem is solved by a pair $(k^*,l^*)$. If we consider the general cost minimization problem
$$
\min_{k,l} \ r \cdot k + w \cdot l 
$$
s.t.
$$
q = f(k,l),
$$
the pair $(q \cdot k^*,q \cdot l^*)$ has to be an optimal solution because of CRS.

---

**Proof.** 
The pair $(k^*,l^*)$ was optimal for the unit cost minimization problem, thus for all pairs $(k',l')$ where
$1 = f(k', l')$, we have
$$
r \cdot k^* + w \cdot l^* \leq r \cdot k' + w \cdot l'.
$$
Now let us move on to the general cost minimization problem where the constraint is
$$
q = f(k,l).
$$
For any feasible pair $(\hat{k},\hat{l})$, define
$$
k' = \frac{\hat{k}}{q} \\ l' = \frac{\hat{l}}{q}.
$$
Because of CRS, this new pair $(k',l')$ produces exactly one unit of output, thus we know that
$$
r \cdot k^* + w \cdot l^* \leq r \cdot k' + w \cdot l'.
$$
holds. Multiplying this by $q$ we have
$$
r \cdot q \cdot k^* + w \cdot q \cdot  l^*
\leq
r \cdot q \cdot k' + w \cdot q \cdot l'
=
r \cdot \hat{k} + w \cdot \hat{l}.
$$
Again because of CRS, the pair $(q \cdot k^*,q \cdot l^*)$ results in $q$ units of output. Thus we have seen that $(q \cdot k^*,q \cdot l^*)$ is a feasible solution that costs no more than any other pair $(\hat{k},\hat{l})$, making $(q \cdot k^*,q \cdot l^*)$ an optimal solution to the general cost minimization problem. QED

---

The solution to the cost minimization problem shows the demanded/used amount of  capital and labor, thus these are indeed linear in $q$.